# the order in Pay To The Order Of

Tags: word-meaning

In bank check ,we can see "pay to the order of".`pay to the order of tom`  means that `pay my money in the bank to tom`,what does `order` mean here?

1.`pay to` is a whole part,`the order of tom`  is another whole  part.Or `pay to the order of` is a whole part?

2.`order` here means :

```
 a. command , instruction
 b. willing
 c. request
 d. rule
```

Answer (score 1):

I think *order* there means the *instruction* of the receiver of the check. The recipient of the check must endorse or sign it for it to be cashed. The phrase *pay to the order of* is contrasted with *pay to bearer*, which doesn't require an endorsement by an individual, as explained here:

[Investopedia *pay to order*](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pay-to-order.asp)

> What Is Pay to Order?
> Pay to order describes a check or draft that must be paid via endorsement and delivery. Pay-to-order instruments are negotiable checks or drafts that are generally written as "pay to X or pay to the order of X." The name entered here indicates the specific person, group, or organization that the payer authorizes to receive the money. **Pay-to-order instruments stand in contrast to pay-to-bearer instruments, which do not require an endorsement.**

[emphasis added]

However, you can't just plug in a synonym of *order* and expect the whole phrase to mean the same thing. It's a fixed phrase with an accepted legal meaning.

Comment: What is a "check"?

Comment: What a ckstion!

Comment: I wasn't joking about the spelling, rather the very idea of checks/cheques. There was a plan to abolish them in the UK by 2018 but it was dropped, however hardly anyone uses them any more. I have a book issued in 2007 and it has had 2 cheques used. Cash is going the same way.

Comment: "Cash" by the way is like a metal or paper form of bitcoin that that used to be used in the 20th and early parts of the 21st century... (this is a message for the future)

Comment: I still use them for payments to individuals, like family Christmas gifts, and to government when any alternative would would require adding a dollar or two.